# Why would this light beam look different from different directions?

Tags: visible-light, scattering

I noticed a weird phenomena while in a particulate-filled restaurant with a sunbeam through a window. While facing the sun, the light beam was quite visible, but as you rotated towards facing away from the sun, the effect gradually diminished. Why is this? I would have expected the particulates to behave the same regardless of orientation, much like looking at the beam from a bright  laser pointer.

- The background had consistent illumination throughout rotation
- I'm not looking at the sun during the session
- I suspect this is a similar effect to sunsets. Facing the sun the sky is white/red/etc but gradually fades to blue as you turn away.

Here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlBLLIzyz4Q with the relevant frames below:

Facing sun:
[image: Light beam visible while facing sun]

90 degrees to sun:
[image: light beam not visible facing away from sun]

Comment: "While facing the sun, the light beam was quite visible, but as you rotated towards facing away from the sun, the effect gradually diminished. "

Roughly: the photons of the beam from the sun scatter off the particles at an angleto the beam; as the angle of the scattered beam gets larger, the less the number of photons. Complete backward scattering is much less probable.

Comment: What remains odd is the magnitude of the effect compared to how little a green laser pointer varies in brightness based on the angle. Maybe it has something to do with the smoke particles?

Comment: A laser beam scatters quantum mechanically, keeping its quantum coherence. There is no/little  coherence in the em waves from the sun.

Comment: True, however...I tried again with a focused LED light (incoherent) and observed the same phenomena as the laser beam. Very nearly the same from every angle.